# Where to catch Entity Framework Exceptions?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following controller in an .NET Core API application:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostCar([FromBody] Car car)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _context.Car.Add(car);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetCar", new { id = car.Id }, car);
}
```

How should I go about catching (and displaying) any errors that might happen during `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`?

It's possible to slip data past `IsValid()` and still have the save fail, leaving an unhelpful `500` behind. I need to capture a detailed error that offers some clue as to what went wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use try/catch for the specific area you are seeing failures, or use an exception filter

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: 1. You can try/catch around the _context.SaveChangesAsync, and present a useful error page based on what errors you encounter. This will handle specific errors like connectivity to your database, any rules that you are violating etc.
2. You can use a more generic approach where you add an exception filter - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters and handle per action or global exception. It gives you a chance to write stuff out to the user directly.
3. You can use appinsights (super easy in Azure) to see what exception your users are seeing and fix them

Answer (score 2):

`ModelState.IsValid` should catch most errors, if you have proper `Data Annotations` attributes such as `StringLength` and `Required`.  However, you cannot foresee any possible error.

I *personally* do not like to use try and catch block inside *each* action method. Instead, I'll use Logging Framework like [NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging) or [Log4Net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/), and display an user friendly error message to user.

With those logging framework, you can either save log into a file or a database. The following is the sample code saving log into database using NLog.

*FYI: as of today, [AdoNetAppender](http://AdoNetAppender) is not available in Log4Net for .NET Core.*

### Startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
 {
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Common/Error/{0}");
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Common/Error");
        }

        loggerFactory.AddNLog();
        app.AddNLogWeb();
        LogManager.Configuration.Variables["connectionString"] = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        ...
    }
}
```

### nlog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<!--
  NOTE: Use this to log internal error, if you have issue configuring NLog.

  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Warn"
      internalLogFile="C:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">
-->

<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
    <target name="database" xsi:type="Database">
      <connectionString>${var:connectionString}</connectionString>
      <!-- 
          Script for creating the dbo.Log table.

          SET ANSI_NULLS ON
          GO
          SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
          GO
          CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Logs](
              [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
              [Application] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
              [Logged] [datetime] NOT NULL,
              [Level] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
              [Action] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
              [Controller] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
              [Identity] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
              [Referrer] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
              [UserAgent] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
              [Url] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
              [Message] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
              [Logger] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
              [Callsite] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
              [Exception] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
           CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Logs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
          (
              [Id] ASC
          )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
          ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

          GO
        -->
      <commandText>
        INSERT INTO dbo.Logs (Application,Logged,[Level],Action,Controller,[Identity],Referrer,UserAgent,Url,Message,Logger,Callsite,Exception)
        VALUES (@Application,@Logged,@Level,@Action,@Controller,@Identity,@Referrer,@UserAgent,@Url,@Message,@Logger,@Callsite,@Exception);
      </commandText>
      <parameter name="@Application" layout="ASP" />
      <parameter name="@Logged" layout="${date}" />
      <parameter name="@Level" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@Action" layout="${aspnet-MVC-Action}" />
      <parameter name="@Controller" layout="${aspnet-MVC-Controller}" />
      <parameter name="@Identity" layout="${aspnet-User-Identity}" />
      <parameter name="@Referrer" layout="${aspnet-Request-Referrer}" />
      <parameter name="@UserAgent" layout="${aspnet-Request-UserAgent}" />
      <parameter name="@Url" layout="${aspnet-Request-Url}" />
      <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@Logger" layout="${logger}" />
      <parameter name="@CallSite" layout="${callsite:filename=true}" />
      <parameter name="@Exception" layout="${exception:tostring}" />
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- Skip Microsoft logs, and log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="database" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

### Usage

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(
        ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _logger.LogError("Test Exception");
        return View();
    }
}
```